# WKHTTPCookieStore HTTPCookieStorage synchronization class

Tags: cookies, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration, wkhttpcookiestore

Use case: I have two `WKWebView`s, one in a main app and one in an app extension. I want them to share the same cookie store.

Apple APIs have 2 different cookie storage classes: `WKHTTPCookieStore` and `HTTPCookieStorage`.

Apple also has `sharedCookieStorage(forGroupContainerIdentifier identifier: String) -> HTTPCookieStorage` for `URLSession`s (not `WKWebView`s) to use across Apps/Build Targets/Extensions.

My plan is to transfer one `WKWebKit` cookies to the sharedCookieStorage and then again to the other `WKWebKit` cookie store.

Before I write one, does anyone have a simple wrapper class that takes in these classes, observes them, and keeps them synchronized?

Or is there otherwise a simpler way to do this seemingly very common use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I put together. Important things to keep in mind:

- `WKWebView` cookies are set and fetched asynchronously, hence the number of callbacks
- There is an observer class attached to `WKHTTPCookieStore`. It's not perfect, but `cookiesDidChange` methods are there for manually updating, say after page loads
- You should instantiate and load `WKWebView` within the `addCookieStore` callback to ensure the store is sync'd before the page is loaded
- Stores that are added are initially sync'd to the first store added. You should nest the `addCookieStore` callbacks to ensure the proper order

(Sorry I couldn't use Combine for compatibility reasons)

Code:

```
import WebKit
import Foundation

class CookieSync : NSObject, WKHTTPCookieStoreObserver {
    var wkStores = [WKHTTPCookieStore]();
    var sessionStores = [HTTPCookieStorage]();
    
    static let debug = false
    
    //The first store added is the canon
    func addCookieStore(_ store: WKHTTPCookieStore, callback:(()->())?) {
        wkStores.append(store)
        
        store.getAllCookies { (cookies) in
            if CookieSync.debug { print("Adding WK:\(cookies.count)") }
            store.add(self)
            if self.sessionStores.count > 0 {
                self.synchronizeAll(self.sessionStores[0]) {
                    store.getAllCookies { (cookies) in
                        if CookieSync.debug { print("Added WK:\(cookies.count)") }
                        callback?()
                    }
                }
            } else if self.wkStores.count > 1 {
                self.synchronizeAll(self.wkStores[0]) {
                    store.getAllCookies { (cookies) in
                        if CookieSync.debug { print("Added WK:\(cookies.count)") }
                        callback?()
                    }
                }
            } else {
                callback?()
            }
        }
    }
    
    //The first store added is the canon
    func addCookieStore(_ store: HTTPCookieStorage, callback:(()->())?) {
        sessionStores.append(store)
        if CookieSync.debug { print("Adding S:\(store.cookies?.count ?? 0)") }
        
        if wkStores.count > 0 {
            synchronizeAll(wkStores[0]) {
                if CookieSync.debug { print("Added S:\(store.cookies?.count ?? 0)") }
                callback?()
            }
        } else if sessionStores.count > 1 {
            synchronizeAll(sessionStores[0]) {
                if CookieSync.debug { print("Added S:\(store.cookies?.count ?? 0)") }
                callback?()
            }
        } else {
            callback?()
        }
    }
    
    //There is no Observer callback for HTTPCookieStorage
    func cookiesDidChange(in cookieStore: HTTPCookieStorage) {
        synchronizeAll(cookieStore) {
            if CookieSync.debug { print("Synced S:\(cookieStore.cookies?.count ?? 0)") }
        }
    }
    
    func cookiesDidChange(in cookieStore: WKHTTPCookieStore) {
        synchronizeAll(cookieStore) {
            cookieStore.getAllCookies { (cookies) in
                if CookieSync.debug { print("Synced WK:\(cookies.count)") }
                for cookie in cookies {
                    if CookieSync.debug { print("\(cookie.name) = \(cookie.value)") }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    //Private
    fileprivate func synchronizeAll(_ to: WKHTTPCookieStore, callback:(()->())?) {

        let dispatch = DispatchGroup()
        let queue = Thread.isMainThread ? DispatchQueue.main : DispatchQueue(label: "cookie_sync1")
    
        for store in self.wkStores {
            if store == to { continue }
            
            dispatch.enter()
            self.removeAllCookies(store) {
            
                dispatch.enter()
                to.getAllCookies { (cookies) in
                    for cookie in cookies {
                        dispatch.enter()
                        store.setCookie(cookie) {
                            dispatch.leave()
                        }
                    }
                    dispatch.leave()
                }
                dispatch.leave()
            }
        
        }
        
        for store in self.sessionStores {
            self.removeAllCookies(store)
            
            dispatch.enter()
                to.getAllCookies { (cookies) in
                    for cookie in cookies {
                        store.setCookie(cookie)
                    }
                    dispatch.leave()
                }
        }
    
    
        dispatch.notify(queue: queue) {
            callback?()
        }
    }
    
    fileprivate func synchronizeAll(_ to: HTTPCookieStorage, callback:(()->())?) {

        guard let cookies = to.cookies else { callback?(); return; }
        
        let queue = Thread.isMainThread ? DispatchQueue.main : DispatchQueue(label: "cookie_sync2")
        let dispatch = DispatchGroup()
        
        for store in self.sessionStores {
            if store == to { continue }
            
            self.removeAllCookies(store)

            for cookie in cookies {
                store.setCookie(cookie)
            }
        }
        
        for store in self.wkStores {

            dispatch.enter()
            self.removeAllCookies(store) {
                
                for cookie in cookies {
                    dispatch.enter()
                    store.setCookie(cookie) {
                        dispatch.leave()
                    }
                }
                dispatch.leave()
            }
        }
        
        dispatch.notify(queue: queue) {
            callback?()
        }
    }
    
    fileprivate func removeAllCookies(_ store: WKHTTPCookieStore, callback:(()->())?) {
        let queue = Thread.isMainThread ? DispatchQueue.main : DispatchQueue(label: "cookie_delete")
        
        let dispatch = DispatchGroup()
        
        dispatch.enter()
        store.getAllCookies { (cookies) in
            for cookie in cookies {
                dispatch.enter()
                store.delete(cookie) {
                    dispatch.leave()
                }
            }
            dispatch.leave()
        }
        dispatch.notify(queue: queue) {
            callback?()
        }
    }
    
    fileprivate func removeAllCookies(_ store: HTTPCookieStorage) {
        guard let cookies = store.cookies else { return }
        for cookie in cookies {
            store.deleteCookie(cookie)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Can you provide examples of using your CookieSync for WKWebView, URLRequests?